# XSL for Xml to table transformation for two rows and many columns

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I have been trying to work on a variation of a question I asked last week.

[XSL for Xml to table transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131529/xsl-for-xml-to-table-transformation).

I have to output the the first and last page number of each section into a table with two rows.

I'm confused on how integrate a two row table with the Muenchian grouping Method

The XSLT 1.0 Solution is what I need. I have solution below for one, but I need two rows.

Any advice or guidance will be much appreciate.

Input:

```
<root>
  <page number="1" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="2" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="3" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="4" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="5" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="6" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="7" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="8" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="9" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="10" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="11" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="12" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="13" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="14" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="15" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="16" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="17" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="18" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="19" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="20" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="21" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="22" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="23" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="24" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
 </root>
```

Output:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Arsenal</td>
<td></td>
<td>Chelsea</td>
<td></td>
<td>ManU</td>
<td></td>
<td>ManCity</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>19</td>
<td>24</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is my current XSLT logic.

```
<table>
<tr>
<xsl:apply-templates select="page[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kSection', @section))]"/>
</tr>                       
</table>
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="page">
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="@section"/>
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="@number"/>
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="key('kSection', @section)[last()]/@number"/>
</td>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Regards JJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k" match="page" use="@section"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="page[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', @section))]"/>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="page[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', @section))]" mode="page"/>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="page">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="page" mode="page">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@number"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="key('k', @section)[last()]/@number"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Arsenal</td>
    <td />
    <td>Chelsea</td>
    <td />
    <td>ManUnited</td>
    <td />
    <td>ManCity</td>
    <td />
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>24</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

first you need to group `section` wise  then get first and last node in `for-each`

```
Group by `section`
  for-each `section`
    if position =1 or position = last
      print it
```

Here is a xsl 1.0 grouping example reference. Hope you can proceed

[XSLT select only last version element in rowset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174409/xslt-select-only-last-version-element-in-rowset/13174595#13174595)

**In xslt **

```
<xsl:key name="k" match="page" use="@section"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="page[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', @section))]">
                <td  colspan="2">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>    
        <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="page[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', @section))]">
            <xsl:variable name="key">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each select="../page[@section=$key]">
                <xsl:if test="(position() = 1) or (position() = last())">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current()/@number"/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Confused about how I can use this solution in my XSLT shown above. Totally confused.

Comment: @jay.james.666 ok, I will explain this in detail then u can get it.

Comment: @jay.james.666 another one xslt which I explained. :-)