# Extracting a class from the section attribute using xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I have a XSLT question which follows on from the question I asked last week.
[XSL for Xml: Inserting specific classes using XSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353255/xsl-for-xml-inserting-specific-classes-using-xsl)

The challenge is to insert classes according to the section attribute. I have an example XSLT solution from my previous question provided by @Kirill Polishchuk, but I can not this solution if I have very large data set.

I just need to extract the text after the underscore in the section attribute and use it as a class in the output xml. I'm puzzled at the moment.

Please note I'm working with XSLT 1.0. Any advice or guidance will be much appreciate.

Thank You JJ.

Input:

```
<root>
  <page number="1" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="2" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="3" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="4" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="5" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="6" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="7" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="8" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="9" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="10" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="11" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="12" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="13" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="14" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="15" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="16" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="17" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="18" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="19" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="20" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="21" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="22" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="23" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="24" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
 </root>
```

Output:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</td>
<td></td>
<td class="Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</td>
<td></td>
<td class="Finances">Arsenal_Finances</td>
<td></td>
<td class="Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>19</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>24</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly modified XSLT from my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13225163/787016. It adds `class` attribute and uses `substring-after` function to extract right part of `section` attribute.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k" match="page" use="@section"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="page[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', @section))]"/>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="page[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', @section))]" mode="page"/>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="page">
    <td class="{substring-after(@section, '_')}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="page" mode="page">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@number"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="key('k', @section)[last()]/@number"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks again. @Kirill Polishchuk. Can you recommended a book to help me with my XSLT adventures.

Comment: @jay.james.666, You're welcome. Look at this one: http://www.amazon.com/XSLT-Cookbook-Solutions-Examples-Developers/dp/0596009747/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1353389457&sr=8-3&keywords=xslt