# XSLT transformation into fixed table structure

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a question regarding XSLT transformation for ouput tables with fixed structure and variable input content.

I have outlined 2 different example.

The desired output table is 6 columns and two row.

But the desired td classes and content are dependent on the input XML

I have a previous example to start from provided by @Kirill Polishchuk

[Extracting a class from the section attribute using xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466641/extracting-a-class-from-the-section-attribute-using-xsl)

Please note I'm working with XSLT 1.0. Any advice or guidance will be much appreciate.

Example 1

Input XML with 6 sections

```
<root>
  <page number="1" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="2" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="3" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="4" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="5" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="6" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="7" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="8" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="9" section="Arsenal_Support">Arsenal_Support</page> 
  <page number="10" section="Arsenal_Support">Arsenal_Support</page> 
  <page number="11" section="Arsenal_Support">Arsenal_Support</page> 
  <page number="12" section="Arsenal_Support">Arsenal_Support</page> 
  <page number="13" section="Arsenal_Revenue">Arsenal_Revenue</page> 
  <page number="14" section="Arsenal_Revenue">Arsenal_Revenue</page> 
  <page number="15" section="Arsenal_Revenue">Arsenal_Revenue</page> 
  <page number="16" section="Arsenal_Revenue">Arsenal_Revenue</page> 
  <page number="17" section="Arsenal_Cost">Arsenal_Cost</page> 
  <page number="18" section="Arsenal_Cost">Arsenal_Cost</page> 
  <page number="19" section="Arsenal_Cost">Arsenal_Cost</page> 
  <page number="20" section="Arsenal_Cost">Arsenal_Cost</page> 
  <page number="21" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="22" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="23" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="24" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
 </root>
```

Desired Output 6 rows & 2 columns

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="Stadium">Stadium</td>
<td class="Crowds">Crowds</td>
<td class="Support">Support</td>
<td class="Revenue">Revenue</td>
<td class="Cost">Cost</td>
<td class="Outlook">Outlook</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="Stadium_R2">1-4</td>
<td class="Crowds_R2">5-6</td>
<td class="Support_R2">7-10</td>
<td class="Revenue_R2">11-14</td>
<td class="Cost_R2">15-18</td>
<td class="Outlook_R2">19-22</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Example 2

Input XML 4 sections

```
<root>
  <page number="1" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="2" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="3" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="4" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="5" section="Arsenal_Support">Arsenal_Support</page> 
  <page number="6" section="Arsenal_Support">Arsenal_Support</page> 
  <page number="7" section="Arsenal_Support">Arsenal_Support</page> 
  <page number="8" section="Arsenal_Support">Arsenal_Support</page> 
  <page number="9" section="Arsenal_Cost">Arsenal_Cost</page> 
  <page number="10" section="Arsenal_Cost">Arsenal_Cost</page> 
  <page number="11" section="Arsenal_Cost">Arsenal_Cost</page> 
  <page number="12" section="Arsenal_Cost">Arsenal_Cost</page> 
  <page number="13" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="14" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="15" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="16" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
 </root>
```

Desired Output 6 rows & 2 columns

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="Stadium">Stadium</td>
<td class="Support">Support</td>
<td class="Cost">Cost</td>
<td class="Outlook">Outlook</td>
<td class="None"></td>
<td class="None"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="Stadium_R2">1-4</td>
<td class="Support_R2">5-8</td>
<td class="Cost_R2">9-12</td>
<td class="Outlook_R2">13-16</td>
<td class="None"></td>
<td class="None"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Regards JJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should do the trick. Note the use of the `NoneRows` template to fill in the extra cells to make 6:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kGroup" match="page" use="@section"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <table>
      <xsl:variable name="groups"
         select="*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kGroup', @section)[1])]" />

      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$groups" mode="top" />
        <xsl:call-template name="NoneCells">
          <xsl:with-param name="count" select="6 - count($groups)" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$groups" mode="pageNums" />
        <xsl:call-template name="NoneCells">
          <xsl:with-param name="count" select="6 - count($groups)" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="page" mode="top">
    <xsl:variable name="sectName" select="substring-after(@section, 'Arsenal_')" />
    <td class="{$sectName}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$sectName" />
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="page" mode="pageNums">
    <xsl:variable name="groupMembers" select="key('kGroup', @section)" />
    <td class="{substring-after(@section, 'Arsenal_')}_R2">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($groupMembers[1]/@number, '-', 
                                   $groupMembers[last()]/@number)"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="NoneCells">
    <xsl:param name="count" />
    <xsl:if test="$count > 0">
      <td class="None"></td>
      <xsl:call-template name="NoneCells">
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your first sample input:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="Stadium">Stadium</td>
    <td class="Crowds">Crowds</td>
    <td class="Support">Support</td>
    <td class="Revenue">Revenue</td>
    <td class="Cost">Cost</td>
    <td class="Outlook">Outlook</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="Stadium_R2">1-4</td>
    <td class="Crowds_R2">5-8</td>
    <td class="Support_R2">9-12</td>
    <td class="Revenue_R2">13-16</td>
    <td class="Cost_R2">17-20</td>
    <td class="Outlook_R2">21-24</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When run on your second sample input:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="Stadium">Stadium</td>
    <td class="Support">Support</td>
    <td class="Cost">Cost</td>
    <td class="Outlook">Outlook</td>
    <td class="None" />
    <td class="None" />
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="Stadium_R2">1-4</td>
    <td class="Support_R2">5-8</td>
    <td class="Cost_R2">9-12</td>
    <td class="Outlook_R2">13-16</td>
    <td class="None" />
    <td class="None" />
  </tr>
</table>
```