# XSLT: Table class dependent on the number of td

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have another question regarding XSLT transformation for tables with fixed structure and variable input content.

I have outlined 2 different examples.

But the desired table class is dependent on the number of sections in input XML.

I have a previous example to start from provided by @Kirill Polishchuk and @JLRishe

[Extracting a class from the section attribute using xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466641/extracting-a-class-from-the-section-attribute-using-xsl)

[XSLT transformation into fixed table structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638508/xslt-transformation-into-fixed-table-structure)

Please note I'm working with XSLT 1.0. Any advice or guidance will be much appreciate.

Example 1

Input XML with 6 sections

```
<root>
  <page number="1" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="2" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="3" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="4" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="5" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="6" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="7" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="8" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="9" section="Arsenal_Support">Arsenal_Support</page> 
  <page number="10" section="Arsenal_Support">Arsenal_Support</page> 
  <page number="11" section="Arsenal_Support">Arsenal_Support</page> 
  <page number="12" section="Arsenal_Support">Arsenal_Support</page> 
  <page number="13" section="Arsenal_Revenue">Arsenal_Revenue</page> 
  <page number="14" section="Arsenal_Revenue">Arsenal_Revenue</page> 
  <page number="15" section="Arsenal_Revenue">Arsenal_Revenue</page> 
  <page number="16" section="Arsenal_Revenue">Arsenal_Revenue</page> 
  <page number="17" section="Arsenal_Cost">Arsenal_Cost</page> 
  <page number="18" section="Arsenal_Cost">Arsenal_Cost</page> 
  <page number="19" section="Arsenal_Cost">Arsenal_Cost</page> 
  <page number="20" section="Arsenal_Cost">Arsenal_Cost</page> 
  <page number="21" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="22" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="23" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="24" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
 </root>
```

Desired Output

```
<table class="col_6">
<tr>
<td class="Stadium">Stadium</td>
<td class="Crowds">Crowds</td>
<td class="Support">Support</td>
<td class="Revenue">Revenue</td>
<td class="Cost">Cost</td>
<td class="Outlook">Outlook</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="Stadium_R2">1-4</td>
<td class="Crowds_R2">5-6</td>
<td class="Support_R2">7-10</td>
<td class="Revenue_R2">11-14</td>
<td class="Cost_R2">15-18</td>
<td class="Outlook_R2">19-22</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Example 2

Input XML 4 sections

```
<root>
  <page number="1" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="2" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="3" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="4" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="5" section="Arsenal_Support">Arsenal_Support</page> 
  <page number="6" section="Arsenal_Support">Arsenal_Support</page> 
  <page number="7" section="Arsenal_Support">Arsenal_Support</page> 
  <page number="8" section="Arsenal_Support">Arsenal_Support</page> 
  <page number="9" section="Arsenal_Cost">Arsenal_Cost</page> 
  <page number="10" section="Arsenal_Cost">Arsenal_Cost</page> 
  <page number="11" section="Arsenal_Cost">Arsenal_Cost</page> 
  <page number="12" section="Arsenal_Cost">Arsenal_Cost</page> 
  <page number="13" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="14" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="15" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="16" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
 </root>
```

Desired Output

```
<table class="col_4">
<tr>
<td class="Stadium">Stadium</td>
<td class="Support">Support</td>
<td class="Cost">Cost</td>
<td class="Outlook">Outlook</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="Stadium_R2">1-4</td>
<td class="Support_R2">5-8</td>
<td class="Cost_R2">9-12</td>
<td class="Outlook_R2">13-16</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kGroup" match="page" use="@section"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:variable name="groups"
       select="*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kGroup', @section)[1])]" />

    <table class="col_{count($groups)}">
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$groups" mode="top" />
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$groups" mode="pageNums" />
      </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="page" mode="top">
    <xsl:variable name="sectName" select="substring-after(@section, 'Arsenal_')" />
    <td class="{$sectName}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$sectName" />
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="page" mode="pageNums">
    <xsl:variable name="groupMembers" select="key('kGroup', @section)" />
    <td class="{substring-after(@section, 'Arsenal_')}_R2">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($groupMembers[1]/@number, '-', 
                                   $groupMembers[last()]/@number)"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your first input:

```
<table class="col_6">
  <tr>
    <td class="Stadium">Stadium</td>
    <td class="Crowds">Crowds</td>
    <td class="Support">Support</td>
    <td class="Revenue">Revenue</td>
    <td class="Cost">Cost</td>
    <td class="Outlook">Outlook</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="Stadium_R2">1-4</td>
    <td class="Crowds_R2">5-8</td>
    <td class="Support_R2">9-12</td>
    <td class="Revenue_R2">13-16</td>
    <td class="Cost_R2">17-20</td>
    <td class="Outlook_R2">21-24</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When run on your second input:

```
<table class="col_4">
  <tr>
    <td class="Stadium">Stadium</td>
    <td class="Support">Support</td>
    <td class="Cost">Cost</td>
    <td class="Outlook">Outlook</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="Stadium_R2">1-4</td>
    <td class="Support_R2">5-8</td>
    <td class="Cost_R2">9-12</td>
    <td class="Outlook_R2">13-16</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```