# XSLT: Extracting output content from the section attribute using xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a variation of a question I asked earlier in regards to extracting specific according to a given input for classes and content.

I have an example solution provided by @Kirill Polishchuk. How do I implement a slight variation for one particular section.

[Extracting a class from the section attribute using xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466641/extracting-a-class-from-the-section-attribute-using-xsl)

I’m using XSLT1.0, I have outlined a possible solution but I'm not if this the best practice. I’m totally confused on how about solving this problem, any advise and help to will appreciated.

INPUT:

```
<root>
  <page number="1" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="2" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="3" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="4" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="5" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="6" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="7" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="8" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="9" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="10" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="11" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="12" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="13" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="14" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="15" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="16" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="17" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="18" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="19" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="20" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="21" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="22" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="23" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="24" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
 </root>
```

OUTPUT

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="Stadium">Stadium</td>
<td></td>
<td class="Crowds">Crowds</td>
<td></td>
<td class="Finances">Finance’s Today</td>
<td></td>
<td class="Outlook">Outlook</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>19</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>24</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

POSSIBLE SOLUTION

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k" match="page" use="@section"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="page[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', @section))]"/>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="page[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', @section))]" mode="page"/>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="page">
    <td class="{substring-after(@section, '_')}">
      <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(@section, '_Finances')">Finance’s Today
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@section, '_')"/>: 
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="page" mode="page">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@number"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="key('k', @section)[last()]/@number"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Regards
JJ.

Comment: `I have a variation of a question I asked earlier ` what is it?

Comment: @pottuamman http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466641/extracting-a-class-from-the-section-attribute-using-xsl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a somewhat more extensible approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k" match="page" use="@section"/>

  <xsl:variable name="rename">
    <item from="Arsenal_Finances" to="Finance’s Today" />
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="uniqueSections"
                  select="page[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', @section))]" />
    <table>
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$uniqueSections"/>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$uniqueSections" mode="page"/>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="page">
    <xsl:variable name="sectionTrimmed"
                  select="substring-after(@section, '_')" />
    <td class="{$sectionTrimmed}">
      <xsl:variable name="renameItem"
                    select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name = 'rename']
                            /item[@from = current()/@section]" />
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$renameItem">
          <xsl:value-of select="$renameItem/@to"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$sectionTrimmed"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="page" mode="page">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@number"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="key('k', @section)[last()]/@number"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here I have an `xsl:variable` where you can list 1 or more item names that should be renamed to other names.  If a match is found, then the `@to` value is used.  If not, then `substring-after(@section, '_')` is used. I've also used variables to capture the values of two formulas that were being used more than once in a single template.