# Extracting the first set of data within the same <root>

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a XSLT question which follows on from the question I asked previously.

The challenge is to extract on the set of data from a repeated set with in the same `<root>`. I have an example XSLT solution from my previous question provided by @Kirill Polishchuk.

[Extracting a class from the section attribute using xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466641/extracting-a-class-from-the-section-attribute-using-xsl)

I just need to extract the first set of data, and ignore the second set starting at number="1"

Please note I'm working with XSLT 1.0. Any advice or guidance will be much appreciate.

Input:

```
<root>
  <page number="1" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="2" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="3" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="4" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="5" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="6" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="7" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="8" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="9" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="10" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="11" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="12" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="13" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="14" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="15" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="16" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="17" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="18" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="19" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="20" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="21" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="22" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="23" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="24" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="1" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="2" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="3" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="4" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page> 
  <page number="5" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="6" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="7" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page> 
  <page number="8" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page>
  <page number="9" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="10" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="11" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="12" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="13" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="14" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page> 
  <page number="15" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="16" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="17" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page> 
  <page number="18" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page>
 </root>
```

Desired Output:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</td>
<td></td>
<td class="Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</td>
<td></td>
<td class="Finances">Arsenal_Finances</td>
<td></td>
<td class="Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>19</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>24</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k" use="@section" match=
  "page[(@number > 1 and count(preceding-sibling::*[@number=1]) = 1)
      or
        (@number=1 and count(preceding-sibling::*[@number=1]) =0)
       ]"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=
          "page[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', @section))]"/>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="page"
          select="page[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', @section))]" />
      </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="page">
    <td class="{substring-after(@section, '_')}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    <td></td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="page" mode="page">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@number"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="key('k', @section)[last()]/@number"/></td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <page number="1" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page>
    <page number="2" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page>
    <page number="3" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page>
    <page number="4" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page>
    <page number="5" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page>
    <page number="6" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page>
    <page number="7" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page>
    <page number="8" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page>
    <page number="9" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page>
    <page number="10" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page>
    <page number="11" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page>
    <page number="12" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page>
    <page number="13" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page>
    <page number="14" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page>
    <page number="15" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page>
    <page number="16" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page>
    <page number="17" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page>
    <page number="18" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page>
    <page number="19" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page>
    <page number="20" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page>
    <page number="21" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page>
    <page number="22" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page>
    <page number="23" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page>
    <page number="24" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page>
    <page number="1" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page>
    <page number="2" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page>
    <page number="3" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page>
    <page number="4" section="Arsenal_Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</page>
    <page number="5" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page>
    <page number="6" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page>
    <page number="7" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page>
    <page number="8" section="Arsenal_Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</page>
    <page number="9" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page>
    <page number="10" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page>
    <page number="11" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page>
    <page number="12" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page>
    <page number="13" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page>
    <page number="14" section="Arsenal_Finances">Arsenal_Finances</page>
    <page number="15" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page>
    <page number="16" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page>
    <page number="17" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page>
    <page number="18" section="Arsenal_Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</page>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td class="Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</td>
      <td/>
      <td class="Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</td>
      <td/>
      <td class="Finances">Arsenal_Finances</td>
      <td/>
      <td class="Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</td>
      <td/>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>24</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Generalisation**:

It is easy to generalize this transformation in order to process the Kth "set.

For example, the following transformation processes the second "set" of the same, provided XML document (above):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k" use="@section" match=
  "page[(@number > 1 and count(preceding-sibling::*[@number=1]) = 2)
      or
        (@number=1 and count(preceding-sibling::*[@number=1]) =1)
       ]"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=
          "page[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', @section))]"/>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="page"
          select="page[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', @section))]" />
      </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="page">
    <td class="{substring-after(@section, '_')}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    <td></td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="page" mode="page">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@number"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="key('k', @section)[last()]/@number"/></td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and again in this case the wanted, correct results are produced:**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td class="Stadium">Arsenal_Stadium</td>
      <td/>
      <td class="Crowds">Arsenal_Crowds</td>
      <td/>
      <td class="Finances">Arsenal_Finances</td>
      <td/>
      <td class="Outlook">Arsenal_Outlook</td>
      <td/>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>18</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Brilliant solution, Thank you so much for your help.